# AJAX unknown issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

*index.php* **(not exact layout just snippits)**

```
        <!-- TRACK LIST -->
        <a name="trackList">
        <div id="trackList" class="container">
            <?php
                include("api/displayTracks.php");
            ?>
        </div>

        // AJAX
        function update(actionUrl, outUrl, div){        
            if (actionUrl != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: actionUrl,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){        
                        $.ajax({
                            url: outUrl,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(html){        
                                $(div).html(html);          
                            },
                        });         
                    },
                });
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: outUrl,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){        
                        $(div).html(html);          
                    },
                });     
            }
        }

        function updateTracks() {
            update("", "api/displayTracks.php", "#trackList");
        }

        setInterval(updateTracks, 5000);
```

I build the function update to try fix this issue, previously i had AJAX calls in many functions but the same problem persisted.
The above code should update the `#trackList` with new content every 5 seconds... But my issue is it isn't doing anything, i haven't much experience with AJAX, this is as far as my knowledge span goes.

I did however place a `alert('test')` inside the update function and it successfully called every 5 seconds. So I've narrowed it down to the ajax.

displayTracks.php **(the functions used in this are included at the top of index.php)**

```
<?php
    // display tracks
    function displayLatestTracks($limit) {
        $sql = sql("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE (rank > 0) AND (isSet = 0) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ".$limit);
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                if ($row['link'] != "") {
                    echo '<div style="background-color:rgb('.randColor().');" id="track-'.$row['id'].'" class="track">';
                    echo '<iframe width="100%" height="20" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url='.$row['link'].'&amp;color=b60000&amp;inverse=true&amp;auto_play=false&amp;liking=true&amp;show_user=true"></iframe>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // display albums
    function displayLatestAlbums($limit) {
        $sql = sql("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE (rank > 0) AND (isSet = 1) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ".$limit);
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                if ($row['link'] != "") {
                    echo '<div style="background-color:rgb('.randColor().');" id="album-'.$row['id'].'" class="album">';
                    echo '<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url='.$row['link'].'&amp;color=c50000&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;liking=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<p class="title">Track List</p>';
    displayLatestAlbums(3);
    displayLatestTracks(10);
?>
```

*sql fucntion:*

```
function sql($query) {
    $sql = mysql_query(strip_tags($query));
    if(!$sql) {
        echo "Error processing query".mysql_error();
    }
    return $sql;
}
```

Comment: Look in the F12 error console, what does it say?

Comment: you are not specifying any method like `get` OR `post`

Comment: no need. there is default method if no method set.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/53bain the error, never knew this tool existed, interesting :P

Comment: @CSGO its not needed.

Comment: your server side has the error. post the php code.

Comment: The problem is in your PHP Code or in WebServer

Comment: need the error too. goto console. click on any one of the item (those in red color) in the left pane. then in the right side, you will find a item call __response__. post what's in there.

Comment: @itachi http://prntscr.com/53bf41 < this you mean?

Comment: not in the `console` tab but in the `network` tab.

Comment: Okay found it and clicked it and but no changes happened

Comment: explain.... did you found the response button? is it a blank response?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/53bo9h Nevermind, had to drag up the bottom

Comment: I found no response button

Comment: dude.... click on one of the requests in red in extreme left. then it will appear.

Comment: It jumps me to the `$.ajax({` line and the `update("", "api/displayTracks.php", "#trackList");` line

Comment: again repeating. click the link in extreme left column. it will open a new window on right pane.

Comment: Sorry, im click repetitively anything i see to the left but the only thing that is happening is it expands with some more details.
So i labeled them, was it 1,2 or 3? http://prntscr.com/53bsp6

Comment: 3rd time repeating. __NOT__ in the `console` tab.... look `Above` in the netwrok tab and corresponding pane.

Comment: Sorry, got you now, this is the responce -> http://prntscr.com/53bvmw

Comment: It would seem it is an issue with the php code... not sure what though, it works the first time around when i call it with `include`...

Comment: post the `sql()` function.

Comment: It's up, i went a head and commented out `displayLatestAlbums(3);` and `displayLatestTracks(10);` in displayTracks.php and replaced it with `echo time();` and it successfully updating, so it must be the two functions.

Comment: put this `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your code and check the response if it changes.

Comment: I get a lot of connection errors; http://prntscr.com/53cc0o

Comment: Fixed! I taken the connection code from the main.php and placed it in a separate connect.php, from there i included it in the displayMyTracks, then i had an issue with multiple declarations of the same function, i simply did the same for them. Over all the issue was how i arranged my php files to include each other.

Comment: @MarcusPrice If you solved the problem, post an answer. Do not add [solved] to your title, that's not how this site works.

Comment: Okay, thanks no problem, will do that! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was in no way anything wrong with the AJAX.
The way i arranged the `include()`'s in my php files deprived my AJAX code from gaining a direct mysql connection, resulting in the callbacks being blank and containing no data.